# wp_get_attachment_image_attributes not working

Tags: images

I move all images to a subdomain.after that there is a problem to show some pictures which have `srcset`. for the home page, I resolve the problem with the below code

```
function alter_image_src($attr)
{
    $attr['srcset'] = str_replace('https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://sub.example.com/', $attr['srcset']);
    return $attr;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_image_src');
```

but it does now work for images which are on post pages.
Images show this way

```
<p>
<img class=" size-medium wp-image-467 alignleft" src="https://sub.example.com/2015/08/Zoom.From_.Sky_small-2.png" alt="Zoom.From.Sky_small" width="300" height="160" srcset="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Zoom.From_.Sky_small-2.png 310w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Zoom.From_.Sky_small-2-100x53.png 100w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
</p>
```

How can I change all `srcset` addresses like the above code. but this time for post pages.

Comment: `string_replace()` only works once.  if you want to replace all instances of a string you're going to need to use `preg_replace()` and convert your strings to proper regex

Comment: @mrben522 if I want to use it once and just for post image, how can I do?

Comment: I misread your question, I'll update my answer shortly.  You still need to use `preg_replace` because the pattern will match multiple times in the srcset string.

Comment: actually this just got super complicated.  you need to use `the_content` filter, and run a regex to find all `<img>` tags, then run that `preg_replace` on each of them in turn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced your `string_replace` call with `preg_replace` and converted your search string to proper regex (I use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for that).  Because you're trying to replace images in the content, which wordpress saves as a string, you need to find anywhere in the content with an image and replace the `src` and `srcset` for it.  This should work (although if you have any script tags with a `src` attribute in it then it would attempt to replace those as well.  You could probably modify that regex to only match `src` and `srcset` within an image tag but that's a bit more advanced than my regex skills will take us.

```
function alter_image_src_in_content($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('~(?:(?:srcset=")|(?:src=")|(?:, ))(https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/)~', 'https://sub.example.com/', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'alter_image_src_in_content');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it works correctly for the home page as same as my code. but for images post the problem is not solve
`https://bit.ly/2MwdEJ5`

Comment: If you have no images where the `src` is showing incorrectly then you can remove `|(?:src=")` from that regex.